# How to clean up overlapping edges?

Tags: edges

See my attachment. There are actually 2 boxes overlap each other but they're not overlap at exactly the same positon. I slided one of the box a bit. So there are edges which are overlap each other , but the vertices not overlapping. How can i clean up the edges ? or let say to remove double edges maybe? so i can keep this shape but having clean edge. Is there an 'auto' way to do it rather than manual edit ? since there's no vertex overlapping , the 'remove double' function can't be used.

I don't want to create anything, i know this topology can be done using edgeloop, but i'm just curious if i can 'heal' this up.

[image]

Comment: do you need the geometry? merging or dissolving the vertices and then adding an edge loop would be the easies way.

Comment: Yes, but not what i'm looking for. It's been mentioned in my post , at the bottom. Looking the automatic way to blend the overlapping edges.

Comment: "remove doubles" should still work for this, just change the merge  distance. You can also limit the "remove doubles" influence by selection.

Comment: I don't want to move the vertices position. Remove double will collapse the vertices, so it will change the topology. I want the exact same topology and keep all the vertices at the original position.  I just want to clean up the overlapping edge

Comment: @andio did you figure it out? If so can you share?